What is the difference between BPN and PN?
In bitbake.conf, I found the definition of BPN and PN.
But I wonder the difference between BPN and PN.
Please explain to me with example.
thanks

In the context of BitBake, a build automation tool used primarily in the Yocto Project for building embedded Linux systems, understanding the difference between BPN and PN is crucial.
PN - stands for "Package Name." It refers to the name of the software package being built. For example, if you're building the GNU C Compiler (GCC), the PN would be "gcc".
BPN - stands for "Base Package Name." It refers to the core part of the package name. For example, if the PN is "gcc-10.3.0", then the BPN would be "gcc".
Example:
Let's say you're building a package for OpenSSL, and the version is 1.2.3. In this case:
PN "openssl-1.2.3"
BPN" openssl"
Understanding this difference is essential because BitBake recipes often refer to BPN, allowing flexibility in handling different versions of the same software package.
Edit
In BitBake, the variable P does indeed include the version, as it's defined as "${PN}-${PV}". Here's what these variables represent:

PN Package Name, which is the core name of the package.
PV Package Version, which is the version of the package.

So, if PN is "gcc" and PV is "10.3.0", then P would be "gcc-10.3.0".
Let's clarify the example:

PN: "gcc" (the core package name)
PV: "10.3.0" (the version)
P: "gcc-10.3.0" (the full package name including version)


Thankyou for your answer. In addition, I wonder about P and PN. In your answer, PN is gcc-10.3.0. But I found that P = "${PN}-&{PV}". If then, Doesn't  PN include version?

I added a further explanation

Is this AI generated? The difference between PN and BPN still doesn't make sense. In the paragraph for PN you give an example where the value is just the package name ("gcc"), but then the paragraph for BPN your example sets PN to be the package name plus the version suffix ("gcc-10.3.0").
